# How to find unique elements in multiple ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, set, unique

I have multiple `Integer ArrayList`, which contains some duplicate elements. I want to get the unique elements from them. But how?
`java.util.ArrayList.removeAll()` is not serving my purpose completely. See the below test code-

```
ArrayList<Integer> d = new ArrayList<Integer>();
d.add(2);
d.add(4);
d.add(5);
d.add(7);
d.add(8);
d.add(9);

ArrayList<Integer> e = new ArrayList<Integer>();
e.add(3);
e.add(7);

d.removeAll(e);

for (int t : d) {
    System.out.print(t+", ");
}
```

In output, i am getting `2, 4, 5, 8, 9,` . Clearly `3` is missing. Also just to keep it simple, I am using only two `ArrayList` here but in my code, i have more than two `ArrayList`.

How I can find unique elements in multiple ArrayList in Java

Comment: based on your code the output that you are getting is obvious. What I understand is as `7` is common, only 7 should be removed and 3 should be added... right? then use `Set`. It will not add duplicates... that way you will have all unique list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Set<Integer>` from your `List<Integer>`. The set will contain no duplicate objects:

```
List<Integer> lstNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//fill the list of integers...
Set<Integer> setNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>(lstNumbers);
//the set will contain no duplicate values...
for (int t : setNumbers) {
    System.out.print(t+", ");
}
```

Note that you can add more `List<Integer>` in the `Set` by using the `Set#addAll` method (as shown in rahulroc answer) to add more integers in your not duplicated elements collection:

```
//assuming setNumbers has been initialized before
setNumbers.addAll(anotherListOfNumbers);
setNumbers.addAll(andAnotherListOfNumbers);
```

Also, as best practice, try to program to interfaces (List, Set, etc), not to class implementations (ArrayList, HashSet), as shown here: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Comment: First, i need to add all the `ArrayList`, then i have to create `HashSet`. Am i right?

Comment: @RaviJoshi yes, first fill the `ArrayList` with duplicate elements, then create the `Set`.

Comment: +1 for the link [What does it mean to program to an interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza .. great that you updated your answer based on my comment. I guess you missed this point from the question

Comment: how about String, is like that too?

Comment: @Muklas yes, this will work fine with `String`s, basically because `HashSet` uses `hashCode` and `equals` methods, and String implements it. You can use your own class to check unique results as well, as long as you use `HashSet` and you class implements these methods as well.

Answer (score 2):

use `java.util.HashSet`

```
Set<Integer> uniqueEntries = new HashSet<Integer>();
for(all lists)
     uniqueEntries.addAll(list);
```

Now the set uniqueEntries will contain all the unique integer values.

Comment: You can use a `Collection<E>` as parameter in the `HashSet` constructor.

Comment: Yes, we can. but he doesn't have just one arraylist. He needs to add multiple array lists. Hence, the constructor wont fulfil the entire purpose as he has to iterate over the whole list of all the arraylists.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Set`

```
ArrayList<Integer> d = new ArrayList<Integer>();
d.add(2);
d.add(4);
d.add(5);
d.add(7);
d.add(8);
d.add(9);

d.add(3);
d.add(7);

// this will remove all duplicates
Set setNew = new HashSet(d);

System.out.print(setNew);
```

### [Demo](http://ideone.com/3iOSS5)

Comment: I like the [DEMO](http://ideone.com/3iOSS5) most. You rock buddy. Thank you. I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<Integer> d = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        d.add(2);
        d.add(4);
        d.add(5);
        d.add(7);
        d.add(8);
        d.add(9);

        ArrayList<Integer> e = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        e.add(3);
        e.add(7);

        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(d);

        System.out.println("d --> " + d);
        System.out.println("e --> " + e);

        d.removeAll(e);
        e.removeAll(temp);
        d.addAll(e);

        System.out.println("d --> " + d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* ArrayList Unique & Duplicate Records Print */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
ArrayList<Integer> d = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        d.add(2);
        d.add(4);
        d.add(5);
        d.add(7);
        d.add(8);
        d.add(9);

        ArrayList<Integer> e = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        e.add(3);
        e.add(7);

        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(e);

        System.out.println("d --> " + d);
        System.out.println("e --> " + e);

        e.removeAll(d);
        temp.removeAll(e);

        System.out.println("e (unique)--> " + e);
        System.out.println("temp (duplicate) --> " + temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much more simpler.

> ArrayList first = new Arraylist<>;  ArrayList second
>   =new ArrayList<>;

```
   first.add("one"); 
   first.add("two");  
   first.add("three"); 
   second.add("two");  
   second.add("three");
```

For find the unique elements..
 first.retainall(second);